# Sound signal plot in python

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing

How can I plot audio signal waveform in Python. My idea was something like this but it is not working

```
    samplerate,data= wavfile.read('bells.wav')
    
    N = 5; # audio duration is 5 seconds
    t = np.linspace(0, N/data, N)
    plt(t, samplerate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `samplerate` is a float number while `data` is the actual signal as a NumPy array.
So you probably want to compute the `t` array using `samplerate` and then plot `data`:

```
samplerate,data = wavfile.read('bells.wav')

N = len(data)   # number of samples
t = np.arange(N)/samplerate     # time array
plt.plot(t, data)
```

Comment: thank you but now i get another error: buffer size must be a multiple of element size

Comment: @Xavi which line of code gives you the error?

Comment: I changed the line samplerate,data = wavfile.read() to samplerate,data = sf.read() and it works now